# I am having trouble installing dlib for my project

Tags: python, dlib

```
C:\python\Scripts>pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.19.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Work\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m0sdf_bv\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Work\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m0sdf_bv\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Work\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-alg_6b9y\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\Work\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m0sdf_bv\dlib\
    Complete output (47 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
        return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
      File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:\python\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Work\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m0sdf_bv\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\python\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\python\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\python\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\python\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Work\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m0sdf_bv\dlib\setup.py", line 129, in run
        cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
      File "C:\Users\Work\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m0sdf_bv\dlib\setup.py", line 120, in get_cmake_version
        out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
      File "c:\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
        return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
      File "c:\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Work\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m0sdf_bv\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Work\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m0sdf_bv\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Work\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-alg_6b9y\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

This is the error that comes when i run pip install dlib

[image]

Comment: It seems it's a known issue - https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/1872

Comment: it is for linux, im using a window, ive downloaded the dlib from here https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/ and still same issue , is there a simple way to install dlib without any hustle ?